# Is $ \pi\mapsto(s\mapsto L(s,\pi)) $ bijective?

Tags: number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Let  $ \pi $ be an automorphic representation of  $ \operatorname{GL_{n}}(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}) $ and  $ L(s,\pi) $ the associated L-function. Is the map  $ \pi\mapsto L(s,\pi) $ bijective ? In other words, is the knowledge of  $ L(s,\pi) $ exactly equivalent to the knowledge of  $ \pi $ itself ?

Comment: How an irreducible automorphic representation is defined by the isomorphism classes (Satake parameters - local L-functions) of its local representations is in every text https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity-one_theorem

Comment: In this setting an automorphic representation isn't a function $f : GL_n(Q) \setminus GL_n(A_Q) \to \mathbb{C}$ but the abstract linear maps acting on the vector space generated by the (right) translates of $f$. So $f(.g)$ isn't the same function as $f$ but it is the same representation.

Comment: Call $f : GL_n(Q) \setminus GL_n(A_Q) \to \mathbb{C}$ an automorphic form and $\pi(f)$ its automorphic representation (so $\pi(f)(g)$ is the linear map sending $x \mapsto u(x)=\sum_j a_j f(xy_j)\in V(f)$ to $x \mapsto u(xg) \in V(f)$). If $\pi(f_1),\pi(f_2)$ are two irreducible automorphic representations then $\pi(f_1+f_2)$ is an automorphic representation. What is its decomposition in direct sum of irreducible automorphic representations ? What is its L-function ?

Comment: Look up "strong multiplicity one".